# Running "foreman" task Fatal error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, foreman

Running grunt on Yeoman Angular project resulted:

Running "foreman" task 
Fatal error: spawn ENOENT

Log file:
https://gist.github.com/kwakwak/da949e17a99367acfc7e

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: `ENOENT` is usually associated with a file not being found.

Comment: You can learn about what causes this error on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent